# I use typescript and vue but the IntelliSense is wrong

Tags: typescript, vue.js

[image]

```
export class AuthService {
  constructor() {}
  test: string = 'asdasd'
  lala: string = 'we'
  test2: string = 'ada'
```

}

In my .ts file, i define a class and it has a test2 property.

[image]

```
<script lang="ts">
  import { AuthService } from './authService.service.ts'

  new AuthService().test2
<script>
```

but in my .vue file, when i use the class, i find it is wrong.
It is saying i have not define the test2 property.

I am using vetor extensions.

Comment: And it can run only the prompt make me feel not good

Comment: Use the code blocks, not images to show your code.

Comment: @AdrienBrunelat  I have updated it.

Comment: @AdrienBrunelat It can run,  but it prompt wrong.